# Get show hide event of masterview controller for UISplitViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I am working on a project which is Master-Detail in architecture and it is an universal application. I have a search control in my navigation bar of DetailViewController. When I begin searching and at the same time if I slide/tap on left bar button to show `MasterViewController` the keyboard is not dismissing.

I want to get the show/hide event for the `MasterviewController`.

Comment: Did my suggestion works ?

Comment: makboney i had added screen sort and demo project which solve your problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I have a solution for your problem**
Below is a delegate method which will call when user swipe to display or hide master view and you can write code for hide keyboard in it
**Code:**

```
- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)svc willChangeToDisplayMode:(UISplitViewControllerDisplayMode)displayMode NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(8_0)
{
    // Write code to hide keyboad
    // --------- Code is not tested but it must work ---------------------------
     [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

---

**Sample project**
[Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yjvysz7qxfgp6ob/UICatalogCreatingandCustomizingUIKitControlsObj-CandSwift.zip?dl=0)

**Output**
`Having bug`
[image]

`Solve bug`
[image]

**Step to test**
1] open project in portrait mode.
2] Swipe left to right to open master view.
3] Select "Search".
4] Select "Searchbar embeded in navigation Bar" from detail view.
5] Click on search bar.
6] Swipe left to right to open master view.
7] keyboard will hide and will display materview.

Comment: thanks Jageen for your reply, i tried your code but didn't work. I am not sure whether i am having the same problem of your's :(

Comment: @makboney Is the keyboard is not hiding ? or the delegate i specified is not calling when you hide or show master view ?

Comment: no the keyboard still appearing but the delegate is also called

Comment: frn i just give you delegate which called when master view will show or hide, I am not sure about how to hide keyboard, Your question was to know a delegate. If you will give me the sample code then i can help to hide keyboard else follow link i suggest.

Comment: @makboney try this [[UIApplication sharedApplication] sendAction:@selector(resignFirstResponder) to:nil from:nil forEvent:nil];